# Angular Form with ng-content -> form.valid/dirty etc not working

Tags: angular, forms, validation, ng-content

I want to create a reusable form component to be used like:

```
<my-form>
   <input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"/>
</my-form>
```

The `<my-form>` component looks like:

```
<form>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
```

However the form in `my-form` component does not see elements injected with  any hence form.valid/dirty etc does not update if elements in form change

This problem/issue has been asked a couple times here on stackoverflow, 
see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843307/q-how-to-use-angular-2-template-form-with-ng-content](http://%20see%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843307/q-how-to-use-angular-2-template-form-with-ng-content)

The solution is to add elements manually to the form like:

```
 public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let ngContentModels = this.models.toArray();
    ngContentModels.forEach((model) => {
    this.form.addControl(model);
});
```

}

With this workarround, form correctly updates valid/dirty etc properties, however, every change on the injected element results in firing `ngModelChange` events twice. In my example, the method `onChange($event)` is called 2 times with every change

```
<input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"/>
```

Do you know how to "fix" the manually adding elements workarround? Or is there any other way how to handle forms with `<ng-content>` injected elements?

Answer (score 0):

When you want your component (`my-form`) to be aware of the outer form, you should consider adding it as an input and passing it through:

```js
@Input myForm: FormGroup;
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
```