# How to use Angular 2 Reactive form with ng-content

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-template-form

I have "FormWrapper" Component like that

```html
<form [formGroup]="wrapperForm">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
```

and AppComponent like that:

```html
<app-form-wrapper>
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
  <div formGroupName="userInfo">
    <input type="text" formControlName="email" />
    <input type="text" formControlName="address" />
  </div>
</app-form-wrapper>
```

But I got this error:
[Error preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjTp0.png)

I tried this solution:
[Q: How to use Angular 2 template form with ng-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843307/q-how-to-use-angular-2-template-form-with-ng-content)

but it doesn't work with nested form groups